# Referenced by two projects but the reference for only one is created in the installation

Tags: tfs, reference, installshield

Ive searched for few hours but cant find the answear for the following

i have two projects in the solution, both have the reference to the same dll and both need the same reference in the folder with them. [they are in the diferent folders in the instalation]

Ive added the primary outputs for both projects to the right folders. Both references have set Copy Local to True. But when the setup is done. So i would expect the both references appear in the primary output location

note:

1. we are using TFS build. And my collegue told me that TFS puts all files in one directory and something has to handle them to the final locations? I couldnt find any information about this either.
2. Im not creator of the setup, hes..gone so i cannot get this information in case its somehow custom made.
3. My 1st online question, so im sorry for the typos or not being very exact. I hope you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

To archive this, you can update your build definition to following:

1. Add the two projects to build in "Projects to Build" section and remove the solution from it.
   [image]
2. Set "Solution Specific Build Outputs" to "True" under "Advanced" section.
   [image]

Queue a build, you should get the files copied for each project:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answear, ill try it on monday :) on the 1st look im not sure, but we will see!
And one more thing, the project seems to work without the libraries at their side. Im not sure how it is possible.
To clear it up..
project A needs library 1 and 2 in his folder
project B needs library 1 in his folder

Comment: but the project B seems to be ok aswell..sorry, couldnt edit the comment